# Node.js require module subfolders

Tags: node.js, require, commonjs

The [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js#processing-attribute-tag-names-and-values) module offers additional exports in a script located in 'node_modules/xml2js/lib/processors.js'.

What is the preferred way to **require()** these?

This doesn't work

```
var stripPrefix = require('xml2js/lib/processors').stripPrefix;
```

The following works, but seems unintuitive and looks ugly

```
var stripPrefix = require('./node_modules/xml2js/lib/processors').stripPrefix;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to import it would be:

`var stripPrefix = require('xml2js').processors.stripPrefix;`

It's because `processors.js` is exported as `exports.processors` in the [`main file`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/lib/xml2js.js#L18) of the library. Just FYI, main file is declared in [`package.json`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js/blob/master/package.json#L58).